# OAuth1 sign a request with Crypto.generateHash

Tags: oauth, crypto

I'm trying to connect to a distant API (Netsuite).
I can send a request and get a successful response when connecting with Postman.

But when I try to do the same in Apex I get a 401 response. I checked the signature in Postman and the one generated in Apex, they're different.

I changed the url and credentials for the example but here is what I get in Postman with the values below :

- Url : https://example.com
- realm : ac
- consumer_key : ck
- consumer_secret : cs
- token_id : ti
- token_secret : ts
- Timestamp : 1683715876
- Nonce : oHtOsIFyJoI
- Version : 1.0

When I send a GET request Postman generates the Authorization header :

`OAuth realm="ac",oauth_consumer_key="ck",oauth_token="ti",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",oauth_timestamp="1683715876",oauth_nonce="oHtOsIFyJoI",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="el%2BphqqFYAmceyI1gdqx0SFMSATlcEYLc3aTccw%2B4oI%3D"`

Now I'm trying to generate the same signature with Apex, with of course the same values.

According to these posts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417067/how-a-oauth1-0-signature-is-generated, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35521564/generating-signature-for-api-access-oauth-1-0, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338661/implementation-hmac-sha1-in-python/8339781#8339781, I have generated the following string (with or without `realm` cause I'm not sure) :

```
String data = 'GET&https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com&oauth_consumer_key%3Dck%26oauth_nonce%3DoHtOsIFyJoI%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA256%26oauth_timestamp%3D1683715876%26oauth_token%3Dti%26oauth_version%3D1.0'; //%26realm%3Dac
```

and tried to generate the signature with this code :

```
System.debug(
    EncodingUtil.urlEncode(
        EncodingUtil.base64encode(
            Crypto.generateMac(
                'HmacSHA256'
                , Blob.valueOf(data)
                , Blob.valueOf('cs&ts')
            )
        ), 
        'UTF-8'
    )
);
```

but it gives me either `hzzAxQ6Z581t2ZcSI63LNNetkxG5Cj23TDTEEN%2FqzyE%3D` (without realm) or `6EzKdGNjuuBYg7o5%2F3PYF7twA7bofroyQu8SexdQRuE%3D` when I expected `el%2BphqqFYAmceyI1gdqx0SFMSATlcEYLc3aTccw%2B4oI%3D`.

Probably I made something wrong but I spent hours reading my code and all the resources I could find, I don't know what.

Comment: I confirm realm should be excluded according to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hammer-oauth-10#section-3.4.1.3.1

Comment: Reading the rfc 5849 and, and this article https://mgr.medium.com/how-to-connect-to-netsuite-from-microsoft-power-automate-using-oauth-1-0-1d7670972406 also seems to be confirming the method I used... Still no clue

Comment: I finally installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js used by postman and added some console.log. I had to add an encoded '/' (%2F) after the domain name. It explains for my example, not for my actual issue, but I'll use the same method. I'll try to make a complete answer asap.

Comment: Finally I found the original issue. When connecting to a Netsuite sandbox you have to write the sandbox name in the domain in uppercase, but the toLowerCase method to build the base string was in a if statement and was not executed. Just another silly mistake that stole few hours of my life :)